# check duplicated items

Tags: vba, userform

Is there any way to check duplicated items in one go instead of doing it separately as shown in the code below?

```
Private Sub checkDuplicates(wks As Worksheet)
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
    Dim n, i, j As Long, found As Range

    For n = 0 To ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
        Set found = wks.Range("E4", "E" & lastRow).Find(Me.ListboxResult.List(n, 1))
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Item " & Me.ListboxResult.List(n, 1) & " is duplicated", vbOKOnly, "Duplicated items"
        Else
            Call addToNewRow(wks, lastRow, n)
            
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: So if your listbox item gets found in the E-column, it's a duplicate immediately? What's in your listbox then?

Comment: Don't understand your question: What do you want to achieve that your current code cannot?

Comment: the listbox is for based on the comboboxes I have selected as well as the quantity I input in the textbox with unit in label @Notus_Panda

Comment: I want to check the duplicated items in one go instead of checking them separately. For example, if I have "a" in the listbox and I click submit again, it will say item duplicated. Then if I put another item "b" in listbox, it will say "a" is duplicated. So I don't want that in my program. I want to check if say "a,b,c" are in the listbox and if I click submit again, it should say items are duplicated. @FunThomas

Comment: Ah, so you just want to avoid that the user gets multiple error messages?

Comment: Yeah exactly @FunThomas

Comment: Then have a boolean variable that you set to true if you find a duplicate and move your msgbox outside the loop with an "If boolCheck Then ... MsgBox" setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do this without a loop. All you have to do is to avoid that the duplicate-message is shown to the user within the loop.

Instead, collect all duplicates and when the loop stops (and you found any duplicates), show it to the user.

Your code could look like this:

```
Dim duplicates As String, duplicateCount As Long
For n = 0 To ListboxResult.ListCount - 1
    Dim item As String
    item = Me.ListboxResult.List(n, 1)
    Set found = wks.Range("E4", "E" & lastRow).Find(item)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
         duplicates = duplicates & IIf(duplicateCount = 0, "", ", ") & item
         duplicateCount = duplicateCount + 1
    Else
        Call addToNewRow(wks, lastRow, n)
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
    End If
Next n

If duplicateCount = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Item " & duplicates & " is duplicated", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate item"
ElseIf duplicateCount > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Items " & duplicates & " are duplicated", vbOKOnly, duplicateCount & "Duplicate items"
End If
```

Comment: I think there's an error that says 'Method 'range' of object'_ worksheet failed' in this line ```Set found = wks.Range("E4", "E" & lastRow).Find(items)```

Comment: Nevermind. It works fine now. Thanks.